# Google Website Optimiser Control Javascript

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain the javascript that makes up Google's Website Optimiser Control script? Specifically: the first two lines, which seem to be empty functions, and why is the third function wrapped parentheses () ?

As far as I can tell this script is basically writing out a new `<script>` which presumably loads something for A/B testing.

```
function utmx_section(){}
function utmx(){}
(function() { 
    var k='0634742331',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;
    function f(n) {
      if(c) { 
        var i=c.indexOf(n+'=');
        if (i>-1) { 
          var j=c.indexOf(';',i);
          return escape(c.substring(i+n.length+1,j<0?c.length:j))
        }
      }
    }
    var x=f('__utmx'),xx=f('__utmxx'),h=l.hash;
    d.write('<sc'+'ript src="'+'http'+(l.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl':'://www')+'.google-analytics.com'+'/siteopt.js?v=1&utmxkey='+k+'&utmx='+(x?x:'')+'&utmxx='+(xx?xx:'')+'&utmxtime='+new Date().valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+'" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></sc'+'ript>')
  }
)();
```

I've attempted to step through with the firebug debugger but it doesn't seem to like it. Any insights much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside anonymous function it shortens names of document and cookies inside it at first, function `f(n)` gets value of [cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) under name `n`. Then Google reads its cookies and with help of `d.write` it loads its scripts (as I see they are related to Google Analytic). This way it makes [On-Demand JavaScript](http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript) loading... Actually you load these scripts all the time, Google just needs some additional parameters in url, so this is done this way - save parameters in cookie, which next time are used to get script again.

And finally back to the first two magic lines :) After Google loads its script (after executing `d.write`), there are some functions which uses `utmx` and `utmx_section`, as well as definition of these functions, or better to say overriding. I think they are empty at first just because another function can execute it before its real definition, and having empty functions nothing will happen (and no JS error), otherwise script would not work. E.g. after first iteration there is some data, which is used to make real definition of these functions and everything starts to work :)

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 functions are in fact empty, and are probably overridden later on.
The third function is an anonymous self-executing function. The brackets are a convention to make you aware of the fact that it is self executing.
the "f" function looks up the value given to it in the document's cookies and returns it. Then a new script tag is written to document (and requested from server) with these values as part of its URL.

Comment: You will receive a syntax error if you try to remove the parentheses around the self-executing function; they are required to make it a valid expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but what does "self-executing" mean?

Comment: @Richard: this way `(function() {...})();` you define function and execute it; this approach is used to provide scope for variables; in your code example, variables like `k` or `d` exist only inside that function, you can't access them outside; and also you do not create any function in window object, like it would be done this way `function f() {..}; f()` - you create named function in window object, and then execute it.

Comment: @Richard: [JavaScript anonymous function](http://helephant.com/2008/08/javascript-anonymous-functions/) - maybe it is helpful

Comment: @Maxym: Ah ok, got it. It's an anon function that executes, without having to declare it first and then execute it in two steps. I can see why you might want to have a function that is not bound to the window or document via a declaration, but this makes no difference to variable scoping i think: given that the variables are declared with "var" they are scoped locally to the function anyway right?

Comment: @Richard: Just an example to make it clear: create html file, add `<script> var a = 1; alert(window.a); </script>` open this file in browser and you'll get "1" in alert. Now change script to `(function() { var a = 1; alert( window.a ); })()` - you just wrapped previous code in anonymous function, but browser will tell you "undefined". So this is the "why", when you have code which you need to execute only once... It is also used by [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth). Anonymous functions are quite useful ;)